# Accessing another user's table within an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, privileges, ora-00942

I'm writing a stored procedure to copy data from one user's table to another schema. Basically, it is a series of INSERT .. SELECT statements such as this:

```
INSERT INTO GESCHAEFTE
  SELECT *
    FROM TURAT03.GESCHAEFTE
   WHERE kong_nr = 1234;
```

This works fine when issueing from sqlplus (or TOAD for me ;-)) so I know that I have sufficient privileges, but when this is part of stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COPY_KONG
    (pKongNr IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
    AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO GESCHAEFTE
      SELECT *
       FROM TURAT03.GESCHAEFTE
       WHERE kong_nr = pKongNr;
END;
```

I get an Oracle error:

```
[Error] ORA-00942 (11: 22): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

As you can see, I've already inserted an `AUTHID`, but to no avail.

What else can I do? I'm pretty much at the end of my ideas here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The owner of a procedure must be granted privilege to access the underlying objects directly, [**not through a role**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_packages.htm#ADFNS328). To have the same level of access as your procedures, use the following commands:

```
SET ROLE NONE;
```

To access another table from a procedure, you need to be granted SELECT directly, not through a role:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TURAT03.GESCHAEFTE TO <your_user>;
```

[This article by Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/RolesAndProcedures.html) contains additional info.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, quick answer! I was able to directly grant the select to my user and it works now.

Comment: This is very strange behaviour, does anyone have a reference as to why this is like this.

Comment: @reimius: We can only guess at the "why" since the documentation usually doesn't mention a reason for going for a particular implementation. Maybe Oracle choose not to maintain a dependency link between procedures and roles because it could lead to massive decompilation affecting many schemas when a role is modified.

Comment: Your explanation does make a lot of sense.