# Oracle returns 'Table does not exist' for a valid object

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Package `mypackage.bdy` owned by user `mq` has a public procedure `CALCTAX`. This procedure refers to a table `TAXINFO` owned by another `mr`.

**code**

```
 PROCEDURE CALCTAX(P_TAX_END_DAT IN DATE,
                   P_CODE      IN VARCHAR2,
                   P_DEFER      OUT NUMBER) IS

  BEGIN
    IF (P_TAX_END_DAT <= V_FECHA_FIN_PERIODO) THEN
      P_DEFER := 15;
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          SELECT 15
          INTO P_DEFER
          FROM MR.taxinfo T
          WHERE SUBSTR(P_MINOR_CODE, 2, 5) IN T.TAX_CODE_NAME;

      EXCEPTION

      when not found

       ....
```

I get the error `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` while trying to compile the package.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399528/accessing-another-users-table-within-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Try this DCL and then your procedure

```
GRANT SELECT ON MR.TAXINFO TO MQ;
```