# PLS-00201 compiling a procedure in SQL Navigator but not running the same as a script

Tags: oracle11g

I have a SQL script referencing that runs fine when I use sql*plus from user A.

If I copy and paste the code from the script in order to make it a stored procedure in schama A i cannot compile the objects it references in schema B.

```
/* logged on schema A from SQL Navigator */
PROCEDURE MYPROC IS
  myvar  B.MYTABLE.MY_COLUMN%type;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
END ;
```

I get this error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'B.MYTABLE' must be declared
```

But as a script, it runs successfully from sqlplus logged as user A

```
DECLARE
  myvar  B.MYTABLE.MY_COLUMN%type;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
END ;
/
exit
```

Why? How could it run as a script from the same user A?

Comment: Please show code and relevant error messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399528/accessing-another-users-table-within-an-oracle-stored-procedure